# How can I filter messages from Google Calendar?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Google calendar messages (meeting **invites** and **updates**, not meeting **reminders**) have the header

```
mailed-by:  calendar-server.bounces.google.com
```

Alas, filtering by `mailedby:calendar-server.bounces.google.com` or `mailed-by:calendar-server.bounces.google.com` does not work.

**How can I filter the Google Calendar messages?**

At this time I am using

```
subject:("Invitation:" OR "Canceled Event:" OR "Declined:" OR "Accepted:")
```

but this does not include meeting *updates* because their subject sometimes starts with `[Update]` and Gmail filters cannot handle brackets (even with backslashes &c - believe me, I know regexps).